# Load balancer based on CPU utilization

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance, cpu-usage, amazon-elb

How to setup a load balancer between 2 instances based on CPU utilisation?

If my first instance having more than 50% utilisation, second should load.

Comment: You have tagged this as both AWS and Azure. Which one are you using?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein AWS

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the Elastic Load Balancer service on AWS, then it is **not possible to route based upon CPU Utilization**.

From [How Elastic Load Balancing Works - Elastic Load Balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html):

> With **Application Load Balancers**, the load balancer node that receives the request **evaluates the listener rules** in priority order to determine which rule to apply, and then selects a target from the target group for the rule action using the **round robin routing algorithm**. Routing is performed independently for each target group, even when a target is registered with multiple target groups.
>
> With **Network Load Balancers**, the load balancer node that receives the connection selects a target from the target group for the default rule using a **flow hash algorithm**, based on the protocol, source IP address, source port, destination IP address, destination port, and TCP sequence number. The TCP connections from a client have different source ports and sequence numbers, and can be routed to different targets. Each individual TCP connection is routed to a single target for the life of the connection.
>
> With **Classic Load Balancers**, the load balancer node that receives the request selects a registered instance using the **round robin routing algorithm** for TCP listeners and the **least outstanding requests routing algorithm** for HTTP and HTTPS listeners.